# how to insert values into successive database rows from one text input?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i am trying to use this one php file to have one text field input to successively put values on my table columns (q1,q2,q3..) , please help

```html
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
$quest = str_replace("1",$i,'q1');
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
$answer = $_GET['answer'];
$rows = $wpdb->update( 
    'wp_1m4ya4r4gg_users', 
    array( 
        $quest => $answer), 
    array( 'ID' => $current_user_id ), 
    array( 
        '%s',   // value1
        '%d'    // value2
    ), 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
}
?>

<center>
<iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form method="GET" action="" target="votar">
 <img id="image" src="http://soulmatelab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/michael-fenton-512963-unsplash.jpg" />
  <input type="text" name="answer" type='hidden' ><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</center>
```

Comment: What's the issue you are getting?

Comment: when i submit ,i get the same value i first entered in the form written on all the rows in my table .